# How to find the box counting dimension of line segment [0,1]?

Tags: fractals, dimension-theory-analysis, dimensional-analysis, fractal-analysis

I uploaded this question and no one has answered because there were some flaws in the question but I have the text now. Please can some one explain how we arrive on example of line segment to have a dimension of 1.

[image]!

Thank you

Comment: *Please can some one explain how we arrive on example of line to have a dimension of 0.* --- The example you posted is for $[0,1],$ not a line. If you're using "line" to refer to $[0,1],$ then **(1)** its box dimension is $1$ and not $0$ (i.e. you're asking how to prove something false, and so your question doesn't make sense), and **(2)** the text you posted shows that its box dimension is $1$ (i.e. what you're asking, modulo the resulting value being correct, is what *Example 1* shows, and thus again your question doesn't make sense).

Comment: Could your question be how does "$[0,1]$ has box dimension $1$" follow from the the computations in Example 1? If so, then maybe adding the following sentence at the end will help: "Therefore, by the [squeeze theorem for limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), it follows that the box dimension of $[0,1]$ is equal to $1.$

Answer (score 0):

Is this your question?
To cover $[0,1]$ by segments of length $\delta$, the minimum number required is
$N_\delta = \lceil 1/\delta \rceil$.  This means
$$
N_\delta - 1 < \frac{1}{\delta} \le N_\delta
$$
and therefore
$$
\frac{1}{\delta}\le N_\delta < 1 + \frac{1}{\delta}
$$